# Get row data for Treeview from Panda

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, tkinter, treeview

I have a `.xlsx` file and I want to recreate that table in a GUI using a Treeview from TKinter. I have a solution below that gives me the output I want but it's long and I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it. For my application, performance is a concern because I don't have that much power and I think with a larger `.xlsx` file I'll start to see a performance hit.

I also have to assume that I don't know the heading and number of rows but that the number of columns is less than 15

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    xls = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx');
    sheetData = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet-1')

    # Get column headings
    headings = sheetData.columns

    # Convert headings to list
    data = list(headings.values.tolist())

    # Get row count
    rows = len(sheetData)

    # Create tree with the the number of columns
    # equal to the sheet, the id of the column 
    # equal to the column header and disable
    # the 'treeview'
    tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=data, show=["headings"],selectmode='browse')


    # Create column headings on tree
    for heading in headings: 
        heading = str(heading) # convert to string for processing
        tree.column(heading, width=125, anchor='center')
        tree.heading(heading, text=heading)

    # Populate rows --The part that concerns me
    for rownumber in range(rows):
        rowvalue = sheetData.values[rownumber]      # Get row data 
        rowvalue = np.array2string(rowvalue)        # Convert from an np array to string
        rowvalue = rowvalue.strip("[]")             # Strip the string of square brackets
        rowvalue = rowvalue.replace("'",'')         # Replace all instances of ' with no character
        tree.insert('', 'end', values= rowvalue)    # Append the row to table
```

Is there a simpler way to get row data and append it to a treeview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create an easy example to do this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd

# Maybe This is what you want 
def Start():
    fp = pd.read_excel("./test.xlsx") # Read xlsx file
    for _ in range(len(fp.index.values)): # use for loop to get values in each line, _ is the number of line.
        tree.insert('','end',value=tuple(fp.iloc[_,[1,2]].values)) # [_,[1,2]] represents that you will get the values of second column and third column for each line.


win = tk.Tk()
win.wm_attributes('-topmost',1)
# win.geometry("+1300+0")

ttk.Button(win,text="Import it",command=Start).pack()

columns = ("name","gender")

tree = ttk.Treeview(win,show="headings",columns=columns)
tree.column("name",width=100,anchor='center')
tree.column("gender",width=50, anchor="center")

tree.heading("name",text="name")
tree.heading("gender",text="gender")
tree.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

This is my example excel file:

[image]

Result:

[image]